# convolution properties of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

Let $f,g,h  \in D'(R^n)$. How we define the convolution of these functions?
I'm trying to show some properties of convolutions such as

1. $\delta\ast f=f$
2. $(f\ast g)' = f'\ast g=f\ast g'$
3. $(f\ast g) \ast h = f \ast  (g\ast h)$

but I'm stucked. You can also offer sources about distributions in order to help me to understand.

Thank you.

Comment: A good start would be to read the wiki article: [link to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Convolution). Where exactly do you get stuck? And, by the way, the third property for distributions is not always true.

Comment: I found the definition of convolution of distributions in R. J. Beerends's "Fourier and Laplace Transforms" and applying the definition to these examples gave the result.

Comment: Ok, let's start with the first one. Show what you tried to do, how you applied the definition, so we can find the place where you get stuck.

Comment: Actually I couldn't show the commutativity property of convolutions for two distributions which is not written above.